# Discarding changes for model in context

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm implementing a modal `viewController` to insert and update `NSManagedObjects` in `core data`. When the modal is cancelled and the form is in update mode, I want the model to revert back to its original value. Is there a way to get the context to discard changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either reset all elements of model individually, or you can deallocate your entire model using nil and create a new one.